# Where is the outbox on the outdated Outlook UI?

Tags: email

[my inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km9OQ.png)

I"m at an unnamed Canadian university using the old version of Outlook and I have no idea where my sent emails or other folders are.  Only the inbox which I can sort by Date, To, From ,etc.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

When a message gets stuck in your Outbox, the most likely cause is a large attachment. Click SEND/RECEIVE > Work Offline. In the navigation pane, click Outbox. ... Drag the message to your drafts folder, double-click to open the message, delete the attachment (click it and press Delete).

Comment: Hey I'm not stuck just cannot find my Outbox.